# TestClass Queries

Tags: apex

There are few questions on Test class:
1. Keep your class as Private? I read in one of the blogs. I didnot understand - why to write the Class in 'Private'?
2. Do individual classes and Triggers also need to have test coverage  75%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Keep your class as Private? I read in one of the blogs. I didnot understand - why to write the Class in 'Private'?

Test classes can be public to share methods, but generally should be private, as they don't need to be accessed by normal classes. Test methods are not accessible outside of test contexts (e.g. from a controller). For a long time, all test classes had to be private, but this restriction was removed some releases back.

> Do individual classes and Triggers also need to have test coverage 75%?

Classes must have 75% coverage in aggregate when using RunAllTests, or individually have 75% coverage each when using RunSpecifiedTests. Triggers only require 1% coverage.